# Conditions for $\frac{(H\cap K)N}{N} = \frac{HN}{N} \cap \frac{KN}{N}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, quotient-group

I recently asked a question regarding the equality for two apparently different definitions for the projective special unitary group.
([Equality between two definitions of the projective special unitary group](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4395823/534907)). The problem was to show $$\frac{(GU(3,q) \cap SL(3,q^2))Z}{Z} = \frac{GU(3,q)Z}{Z} \cap  \frac{SL(3,q^2)Z}{Z}.$$ Containment from the left to the right is easy to see, but the proof of the other direction was surprisingly nontrivial.

This situation leads me to ask if there are some known conditions on subgroups $H,K,N$ of a group $G$ with $N\trianglelefteq G$ such that $$\frac{(H\cap K)N}{N} = \frac{HN}{N} \cap \frac{KN}{N}.$$ Is this something that holds in general? if not, which conditions are necessary and/or sufficient for this to be the case?

Comment: Writing $\frac{G}{H}$ is bad form, usually; this is because quotient groups are defined by either left cosets (in which case we write $G/H$) or right cosets (in which case we write $H\setminus G$ - but this is rare as, in normal subgroups, left cosets are also right cosets).

Comment: No, it doesn't hold in general. For example, in the Klein $4$-group $G=C_2\times C_2$, with $N=C_2\times\{1\}$, take $H=\{1\}\times C_2$ and $K=\{(1,1),(x,x)\}$. Then $H\cap K=\{1\}$, so the left hand side is $N/N$, the trivial quotient. But $HN=KN=G$, so the right hand side is $G/N$, cyclic group of order $2$ given by the quotient.